# Updating array.length++ to array.push()

Tags: solidity, arrays, solc

There is this piece of code that runs good with solc 0.5.0

```
updateValueAtNow(totalSupplyHistory, curTotalSupply + _amount);
updateValueAtNow(balances[_user], previousBalanceTo + _amount);

/// @dev `updateValueAtNow` used to update the `balances` map and the
      ///  `totalSupplyHistory`
      /// @param checkpoints The history of data being updated
      /// @param _value The new number of reputation
    function updateValueAtNow(Checkpoint[] storage checkpoints, uint256 _value) internal {
        require(uint128(_value) == _value); //check value is in the 128 bits bounderies
        if ((checkpoints.length == 0) || (checkpoints[checkpoints.length - 1].fromBlock < block.number)) {
            Checkpoint storage newCheckPoint = checkpoints[checkpoints.length++];
            newCheckPoint.fromBlock = uint128(block.number);
            newCheckPoint.value = uint128(_value);
        } else {
            Checkpoint storage oldCheckPoint = checkpoints[checkpoints.length-1];
            oldCheckPoint.value = uint128(_value);
        }
    }
```

Wanting to update it to solc 0.7.3, I must get rid of length-- and length++ as per [this spec](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.2/060-breaking-changes.html)

For the love of me though I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. This line is crucial

```
    Checkpoint storage newCheckPoint = checkpoints[checkpoints.length++];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.push()` to increase the length of the array by one.

It will return a storage pointer to the new last array slot, so this should work:

```
Checkpoint storage newCheckPoint = checkpoints.push();
```